# How do I tell which cell in a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How do I see which cell is selected in a UITableView?  I'm just trying to do something simple, but I kinda forgot how to do it. :D Anyway, could some one help me? I want it to be an "if" statement such as:

```
if (/*The first cell got selected*/) {
    self.label.text = @"Hello!"
}
```

Could someone fill out the commented space?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want to do this when the user makes their selection? If so, you need to implement `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in your table view delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello!";
    }
    // ... other row selection logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//table is a reference to your UITableView
NSIndexPath* path = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];
if (path && path.row == 0 ) {
    self.label.text = @"Hello!"
}
```

You can also track changing selected state in UITableView's delegate `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: What class is table? It's undeclared.

Comment: you have to replace `table` with your table's outlet (`self.tableView` may work depending on your configuration)